# Regex for texts inside HTML Tags

Tags: regex, eclipse

I need help in formulating a regex to capture texts that are enclosed in HTML tags.

Example:

```
<div id="test">test</div>
```

`test` should be captured

```
<c:otherwise>
    Hello
</c:otherwise>
```

`Hello` should be captured

I am using this regex `>.+?` but it doesn't seem to capture the 2nd example.

Any idea on how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Any reason you're not just using jQuery's `html()` function?

Comment: [Don't parse HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/2767207) - HTML is way too complicated

Comment: I am trying to find all the hard-coded texts within our project.. I am using Eclipse's search function that supports Regex to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this,

```
>\s*(.*?)\s*<\/
```

`\s*` will match any space character(*both horizontal and vertical*) greedily.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/nI6uL1/2)

Answer (score 0):

Use capture groups to get the text out.  Use a regex something like this:

`<[^>]*>(.*)<\/[^>]>`

Then you can use `$1` to refer to the [captured text](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html).